# incollection: wrong bibliography entry

Tags: biblatex

I'm using biblatex and the following entry in my `*.bib` file leads to a wrong bibliography entry. If I skip the maintitle, booksubtitle and bookauthor it seems that everything works but unfortunately with less information in the bibliography.

I appreciate any help!

This is the structure of the collection.

It's a multi-volume book (volume = 19).
Collection title is "Der Controller Berater".
Title of the volume is Balanced Scorecard.
Volume subtitle is Best-Practice-Lösungen für die Unternehmenssteuerung.
Title of the work in the volume is Balanced Scorecard im Kontext des modernen Performance Measurement.

```
@incollection{GleBSC,
author = {Gleich, Ronald and Quitt Anna},
title = {Balanced Scorecard im Kontext des modernen Performance Measurement},
maintitle = {Der Controlling-Berater}
booktitle = {Balanced Scorecard},
booksubtitle = {Best-Practice-Lösungen für die Unternehmenssteuerung}
bookauthor = {Karliiiii}
publisher = {Haufe-Lexware},
year = {2012},
chapter = {},
pages = {},
address = {Freiburg},
editor = {Gleich, Ronald and Klein, Andreas},
volume = {19},
otherinfo = {}
```

Bibliography:

> [5] Ronald Gleich und Quitt Anna. „Balanced Scorecard im Kontext des
>   modernen Performance Measurement“. In: Der Controlling-Berater.

Comment: There are missing commas after `maintitle`, `booksubtitle` and `bookauthor`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.